# How to make an SVG responsive on sites like codepen.io?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an SVG based site pre-loader. I can not make it responsive. It does not assume the parents's full size. I want it to scale down so that it can take size according to height of the viewport.
https://codepen.io/toughyear/pen/zYxWJOj

```
 <div >
     <svg 
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="449.000000pt"
          height="470.000000pt"
          viewBox="0 0 449.000000 470.000000"
          preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
        >
          <g
            transform="translate(0.000000,470.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
            class="wolf-path"
          >
            <!-- path details--!>
          </g>
        </svg> 
</div>
```

the related css structure is :

```
body {
/*code*/
}

.wolf-path {
/*code*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the height and width from sag element and add a height/width with respect to viewport to the parent div

```
<div style="width:100vw;height:100vh;">
  <svg 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 449.000000 470.000000"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a style to the svg to consume the entire viewport.

Example:

```
div svg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

[Modified Codepen](https://codepen.io/sforsberg/pen/JjoLxrX)